# Trying to set different text color for each segment in UISegmentedControl

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I'll glad for help.

I know how to change the text for selected state using attributedString, but I can't find a way to set a unique text color(or even background color) for each segment.

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Its for selected state, I want a different color for each segment when its not selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create unique background color for selected segment you need to create action for `UISegmentControl` and then based on the index set the color.

```swift
@IBAction func segmentChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            sender.selectedSegmentTintColor = UIColor.red
        } else {
            sender.selectedSegmentTintColor = UIColor.blue
        }
    }
```

Edit:

So you can try to work with subviews of `UISegmentControl` like that:

```
@IBOutlet weak var segment: UISegmentedControl! {
        didSet {
            for (index, view) in segment.subviews.enumerated() {
                if index == 0 {
                    view.subviews.forEach{ label in
                        (label as! UILabel).textColor = UIColor.red
                    }
                } else {
                    view.subviews.forEach{ label in
                        (label as! UILabel).textColor = UIColor.blue
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for default state (when it's not selected, in my 'viewDidLoad'). Either background/text color.

Comment: @IdanMoshe I updated my answer. I tested that code and it works.